# How to convert my bytearray('b\x9e\x18K\x9a') to something like this--> '\x9e\x18K\x9a'<---just str ,not array

Tags: python, string, arrays

How to convert my `bytearray('b\x9e\x18K\x9a')` to something like this --> `\x9e\x18K\x9a` <---just str, not array!

```python
>> uidar = bytearray()
>> uidar.append(tag.nti.nai.uid[0])
>> uidar.append(tag.nti.nai.uid[1])
>> uidar.append(tag.nti.nai.uid[2])
>> uidar.append(tag.nti.nai.uid[3])
>> uidar
   bytearray('b\x9e\x18K\x9a')
```

I try to decode my bytearray by

```python
uid  =  uidar.decode('utf-8')
```

but it can't...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    uid = uidar.decode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Help me Please ...

Comment: What you are asking for does not appear to make any sense. Could you expand and clarify your question by saying what you are trying to accomplish over-all?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you're satisfied with an answer, make sure you mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark icon next to the question.

Answer (score 13):

In 2.x, strings are bytestrings.

```
>>> str(bytearray('b\x9e\x18K\x9a'))
'b\x9e\x18K\x9a'
```

Latin-1 maps the first 256 characters to their bytevalue equivalents, so in Python 3.x:

```
3>> bytearray(b'b\x9e\x18K\x9a').decode('latin-1')
'b\x9e\x18K\x9a'
```