# How to use bytearray in MD5 hash in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.6

python 2.7 and 3.4 can do the following:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(bytearray(128))
```

but python 2.6 generates an error message:

```
    m.update(bytearray(128))
TypeError: update() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray
```

How to fix this in Python 2.6?

Comment: Upgrade to 2.7 :-) But seriously, the source code changes for the md5 lib are open source; I would review the code and patch the md5 lib if upgrading is not an option.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Fix what? If Python2.6 does not support this then it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Python 2.x, you can simply convert the bytearray to a string before passing it to `update()`, e.g.:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(str(bytearray(128)))
```

However, this will yield a wrong result on Python 3.x, because a `bytearray` cannot be converted to a string directly. For a portable version, use the following code which works identically on Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(bytearray(128).decode('latin-1'))
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459067/how-to-convert-my-bytearrayb-x9e-x18k-x9a-to-something-like-this-x9e-x1) for more information on why this works.