# psycopg2 lobject class - insert large objects using bit stream

Tags: python, mysql, types, psycopg2

In `python` + `psycopg2` is it possible to create/write a `Postgresql` large object **using the bit stream** instead of giving in input a path on the file system that point to the local file?

#### Why this requirement

I'm working on a database migration script **mysql > postgresql**. In the source database (mysql) the files binary is stored into a longblob field.

Using the standard approach/method to import large objects into postgresql would be an overkill, since it require a path to a local file in input, for this reason I would have to dump each binary into a OS local file before perform the large object import.

#### What I've tried

Reading the official `psycopg2` documentation at [this link](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=open#psycopg2.extensions.lobject), it seems ( but I'm not sure ) to be possible using the [write(str)](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=open#psycopg2.extensions.lobject.write) method. Which is a wrapper of `lo_write` function.

I've been trying to use this method in many different ways, without succeed. The one got closer I think is this one, but I get a *TypeError*:

```python
cnx_psql.lobject(0, mode='w').write( row['content'] )
    TypeError: lobject.write requires a string; got bytearray instead
```

where `row['content']` is the data I've previously selected from a mysql field of type longblob.

---

Does anybody know how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any information,

If I'm missing something please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st option: foreign data wrapper**

Maybe you could use foreign data wrapper, such as mysql_fdw? http://pgxn.org/dist/mysql_fdw/

With this you can create a foreign table in postgresql database, and then just do

```
insert into new_table select * from foreign_table;
```

... and the server will pull all the records from foreign (MySQL) table into local table, without transferring the data to client side even. You can easily map LONGBLOB in MySQL to bytea in PostgreSQL. bytea type allows for values of length up to 1GB.

To get a bit more of the feel, see http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgresql-playing-with-foreign-data-wrappers-1/ and
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

**2nd option: COPY**

If that's not useful, maybe you can use COPY. Psycopg2's cursor has [good COPY support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from), which accepts a file object, which is basically anything you make it to be, as long as it has .read() and .readline().

**3rd option: fix the error you got.**
If you really know what you're doing and have read [the differences and limitations when using lobject vs. bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-intro.html) and still want to use lobject, then fix the error. Write apparently requires string, but you're passing in bytearray. Converting depends on Python version, see [How to convert my bytearray('b\x9e\x18K\x9a') to something like this--> '\x9e\x18K\x9a'<---just str ,not array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459067/how-to-convert-my-bytearrayb-x9e-x18k-x9a-to-something-like-this-x9e-x1)

**Edit:** Posted a bit too soon.

Comment: many thanks for the answer! I'm evaluating the options you kindly provided to see which one better fits in my scenario